# How can I copy an entire database to another on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to copy a database A into database B (same SQL Server) entirely - what would be the easiest SQL or utility command to do that? (database B should be 100% erased before the copy)

Note that it can be non-SQL thing, but in any case I need to run it as one-click. So some utility that does that is also acceptable as far as I can run  copying with one click or from command line.

SQL Server 2008R2 or 2012.

Best, Askar

Comment: I usually just backup and restore to a new location. Im sure you could write a commandline to do that.

Comment: You need consider lot of things forehead, like do you still want database A accessible during your copy and if so how to handle changes to make sure they are 100% the same. How big the db is, would backup restore faster or simple insert into faster, or even replication?

Comment: There is no version **2010** of SQL Server - you have 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 or 2012 ....

Comment: made solution, David can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a soultion based on David's thoughts. It looks like this (**Prod** - source DB, **Demo** - destination copy)

```
 DECLARE @backup varchar(300) = 'e:\Prod.bak'; 
 DECLARE @logic_db_file varchar(300) = 'koe'; 
 DECLARE @logic_log_file varchar(300) = 'koe_log'; 
 DECLARE @out_db_file varchar(300) = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Demo.mdf'; 
 DECLARE @out_log_file varchar(300) = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Demo_log.ldf'; 

 PRINT N'Backing up Production database.'
 BACKUP DATABASE Prod
    TO DISK = @backup WITH FORMAT;


 PRINT N'Restoring FILELISTONLY, see log file for data.'
 -- Restore the files to Demo
 RESTORE FILELISTONLY
    FROM DISK = @backup

 PRINT N'Getting exclusive access to Demo'  
 Alter database  Demo set single_user with rollback immediate
 drop database Demo



 PRINT N'Restoring backup to Test database'
 RESTORE DATABASE Demo
  FROM DISK = @backup
  WITH REPLACE,
  MOVE @logic_db_file TO @out_db_file, 
  MOVE @logic_log_file TO @out_log_file
 GO

  -- if you want you can do some SQL fixes to newly made DB

  PRINT N'Changing normal users to demo users, if account type is OK'

  USE Demo; 
  UPDATE USER_ACCOUNTS SET ACCOUNT_TYPE=3 WHERE (STATUS=1) AND (ACCOUNT_TYPE=1);  
  GO
```